# Update max over partition where (Excel MaxIF Equivalent in SQL Server)

Tags: sql, sql-server, export-to-excel

**Goal:** I am trying to replicate the Excel MaxIF function.

https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-maxifs-function

**Background:**
I am adding 8m records to a date base and need to be able to split the current records from the historic records (records are updated weekly). These come from an Excel sheet I have loaded into a database.

Basically each record has an ID and a Data, I am looking to return the max data associated with each ID. The max data is the latest record.

**Problem:**
I can get the results via the below query, however I need to be able to insert this is a calculated column that updates the table itself as the data needs to be exported back to Excel for other business users.

**Results example**

| ID | DATE | MAX | BOOLEAN |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1/01/2022 | 1/04/2022 | FALSE |
| 1 | 1/02/2022 | 1/04/2022 | FALSE |
| 1 | 1/03/2022 | 1/04/2022 | FALSE |
| 1 | 1/04/2022 | 1/04/2022 | TRUE |
| 2 | 1/01/2021 | 1/10/2021 | FALSE |
| 2 | 1/05/2021 | 1/10/2021 | FALSE |
| 2 | 1/10/2021 | 1/10/2021 | TRUE |

Query that works:

```
/* MAX WITHOUT CASE */
SELECT [PASSENGERID], [DATE], 
MAX([DATE]) OVER(PARTITION BY [PASSENGERID]) AS [MAX DATE]
FROM [LOCAL DATABASE].[dbo].[DATA$]
where [PassengerID] = [PassengerID]
ORDER BY [PASSENGERID] ASC, [DATE] ASC
```

Various ways to update table I have tried:

1. Using Alter & Max & Case

```
/* 1 ALTER TABLE CASE 
ERROR: RETURNS DATE NOT MAX */
ALTER TABLE [DATA$] 
add [MAX] as (CASE WHEN [passengerid] = [passengerid] THEN [DATE] ELSE 0 END)

/* 2 ALTER TABLE MAX CASE
ERROR: An aggregate may not appear in a computed column expression or check constraint */
ALTER TABLE [DATA$] 
add [MAX] as MAX(CASE WHEN [passengerid] = [passengerid] THEN [DATE] ELSE 0 END)

/* 3 ALTER TABLE MAX CASE WITH SELECT GROUP
ERROR: An aggregate may not appear in a computed column expression or check constraint */
ALTER TABLE [DATA$] 
add [MAX] as 
(select(MAX(CASE WHEN [passengerid] = [passengerid] THEN [DATE] ELSE 0 END))
from [DATA$] 
GROUP BY [PassengerID])
```

2. Using Alter & Max & Partition

```
/* 4 ALTER TABLE MAX PARTITION
ERROR: Windowed functions can only appear in the SELECT or ORDER BY clauses */
ALTER TABLE [DATA$] 
ADD [MAX] as MAX([DATE]) OVER(PARTITION BY [PASSENGERID])

/* 5 ALTER TABLE MAX PARTITION GROUP
ERROR: Subqueries are not allowed in this context. Only scalar expressions are allowed.s */
ALTER TABLE [DATA$] 
ADD [MAX] as 
(select(MAX([DATE]) OVER(PARTITION BY [PASSENGERID]))
from [DATA$] 
GROUP BY [PassengerID])

/* 6 ALTER TABLE MAX PARTITION WHERE
ERROR: Subqueries are not allowed in this context. Only scalar expressions are allowed.s */
ALTER TABLE [DATA$] 
ADD [MAX] as 
(select(MAX([DATE]) OVER(PARTITION BY [PASSENGERID]))
from [DATA$] 
where [PassengerID] = [PassengerID]
```

3. Using Update & Max & Case

```
/* 7 UPDATE TABLE MAX CASE
ERROR: An aggregate may not appear in the set list of an UPDATE statement*/
UPDATE [LOCAL DATABASE].[dbo].[DATA$] 
SET [MAX] = MAX(CASE WHEN [passengerid] = [passengerid] THEN [DATE] ELSE 0 END)

/* 8 UPDATE TABLE SELECT MAX CASE
ERROR: An aggregate may not appear in the set list of an UPDATE statement*/
UPDATE [LOCAL DATABASE].[dbo].[DATA$] 
SET [MAX] = (SELECT(MAX(CASE WHEN [passengerid] = [passengerid] THEN [DATE] ELSE 0 END)))

/* 9 UPDATE TABLE SELECT MAX CASE GROUP
ERROR Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted*/
UPDATE [LOCAL DATABASE].[dbo].[DATA$] 
SET [MAX] = (SELECT(MAX(CASE WHEN [passengerid] = [passengerid] THEN [DATE] ELSE 0 END))
from [DATA$] 
GROUP BY [PassengerID])  

/* 10 MAX OF COLUMN 
ERROR An aggregate may not appear in the set list of an UPDATE statement*/
UPDATE [LOCAL DATABASE].[dbo].[DATA$] 
SET [MAX] = (SELECT(MAX(CASE WHEN [passengerid] = [Passengerid] THEN [DATE] ELSE 0 END)))
from [DATA$] 
where [PassengerID] = [PassengerID]

/* 11 MAX OF COLUMN 
INCORRECT MAX OF COLUMN  */
UPDATE [LOCAL DATABASE].[dbo].[DATA$] 
SET [MAX] = (SELECT(MAX(CASE WHEN [passengerid] = [Passengerid] THEN [DATE] ELSE 0 END))
from [DATA$] 
where [PassengerID] = [PassengerID])
```

4. Using Update & Max & Partition

```
/* 12 UPDATE TABLE MAX PARTITION
ERROR Windowed functions can only appear in the SELECT or ORDER BY clauses*/
UPDATE [LOCAL DATABASE].[dbo].[DATA$]
SET [MAX] =MAX([DATE]) OVER(PARTITION BY [PASSENGERID])

/* 13 UPDATE TABLE SELECT MAX PARTITION
INCORRECT RETURNS DATE VALUE */
UPDATE [LOCAL DATABASE].[dbo].[DATA$]
SET [MAX] = (select(MAX([DATE]) OVER(PARTITION BY [PASSENGERID])))

/* 14 UPDATE TABLE SELECT MAX PARTITION GROUP
ERROR DATE is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause */
UPDATE [LOCAL DATABASE].[dbo].[DATA$]
SET [MAX] = (select(MAX([DATE]) OVER(PARTITION BY [PASSENGERID]))
from [DATA$] 
GROUP BY [PassengerID])

/* 15 UPDATE TABLE SELECT MAX PARTITION WHERE
ERROR Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted  */
UPDATE [LOCAL DATABASE].[dbo].[DATA$] 
SET [MAX] = (select(MAX([DATE]) OVER(PARTITION BY [PASSENGERID]))
from [DATA$] 
where [PassengerID] = [PassengerID])

/* 16 UPDATE TABLE SELECT MAX PARTITION WHERE (CHANGE BRACKET) 
INCORRECT RETURNS DATE VALUE*/
UPDATE [LOCAL DATABASE].[dbo].[DATA$] 
SET [MAX] = (select(MAX([DATE]) OVER(PARTITION BY [PASSENGERID])))
from [DATA$]
where [PassengerID] = [PassengerID]

/* 17 UPDATE TABLE SELECT MAX PARTITION (NO WHERE)
INCORRECT RETURNS DATE VALUE  */
UPDATE [LOCAL DATABASE].[dbo].[DATA$] 
SET [MAX] = (select(MAX([DATE]) OVER(PARTITION BY [PASSENGERID])))
from [DATA$]
```

5. Using Update & Max & Groupby

```
/* 18  UPDATE TABLE SELECT MAX GROUP
ERROR Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted  */
UPDATE [LOCAL DATABASE].[dbo].[DATA$] 
SET [MAX] = (SELECT(MAX([DATE]))
from [DATA$] 
GROUP BY [PassengerID])


/* 19 UPDATE TABLE SELECT MAX WHERE X
INCORRECT RETURNS MAX OF TABLE NOT ID  */
UPDATE [LOCAL DATABASE].[dbo].[DATA$] 
SET [MAX] = (SELECT(MAX([DATE]))
from [DATA$] 
where [PassengerID] = [PassengerID])
```

Query to check data:

```
SELECT [PASSENGERID], [DATE], [MAX],  
CASE WHEN [DATE] = [MAX] THEN 'TRUE' ELSE 'FALSE' END [MAX BOOLEAN]
FROM [DATA$]
ORDER BY [PASSENGERID] ASC, [DATE] ASC
```

Comment: Text in ALL CAPITALS is considered shouting - please do not do it. FYI SSMS is only a client interface for SQL Server - its not the database engine itself.

Comment: I have to admit I have no idea what you are asking. If its not already please ensure its a [mre] with the emphasis on *minimal* i.e. the problem is presented in its simplest form. Also sample data and desired results usually make a question much clearer.

Comment: I assume you are joking about the capitals 

Comment: I'll post an example, but if you not what a max if is it makes sense.

Comment: "I assume you are joking about the capitals" - definitely not.

Comment: "I'll post an example, but if you not what a max if is it makes sense." - if so I suspect that the question could be much much shorter if condensed down to the basics.